# Define strength relation pgadmin 4

Tags: foreign-keys, relationship, postgis, qgis, pgadmin-4

I'm working on a database with different types of relationships between tables, 1:M and M:N. I've already defined the relationships through foreign keys in PG Admin 4.

When I open the model in QGIS I get only association type relations, but for the intermediates tables (M:N Relations, red rectangle) I need composition strength relation.

[image: relations and strenght relation type]

Any idea of how to define the strenght relations in PG Admin 4?

Thanks you all

This is un exemple of the SQL code for one of them:

## #create table Arret

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sdt_transports.arret;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sdt_transports.arret
(
    objectid_arret integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sdt_transports.arret_objectid_arret_seq'::regclass),
    id_arret integer,
    nom_arret character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ref_etat_exploitation integer,
    abreviation_arret character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    arret_regional smallint,
    arret_urbain smallint,
    sens_alle smallint,
    sens_retour smallint,
    url_horaire_passage character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_horaire_passage_exception smallint,
    url_horaire_origine character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_horaire_origine_exception smallint,
    url_horaire_destination character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_horaire_destination_exception smallint,
    url_information character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_information_exception smallint,
    niveau_equipement character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    rem_equipement character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    niveau_offre smallint,
    pers_montante smallint,
    pers_descente smallint,
    url_statistique character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_statistique_exception smallint,
    no_localite smallint,
    commentaires character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    niveau_service character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    user_mise_a_jour character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date_mise_a_jour timestamp without time zone,
    x double precision,
    y double precision,
    geom geometry,
    CONSTRAINT arret_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid_arret)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);
```

## #create table Cadre Horaire

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sdt_transports.cadre_horaire;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sdt_transports.cadre_horaire
(
    objectid_cadre_horaire integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sdt_transports.cadre_horaire_objectid_cadre_horaire_seq'::regclass),
    id_cadre_horaire character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    nom_cadre_horaire character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_cadre_horaire character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    url_cadre_horaire_exception smallint,
    commentaires character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    user_mise_a_jour character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date_mise_a_jour timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT cadre_horaire_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid_cadre_horaire)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
```

## #Create intermediate table bewteen Arret and Cadre Horaire

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sdt_transports.link_arret_cadre_horaire;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sdt_transports.link_arret_cadre_horaire
(
    objectid_link_arret_cadre_horaire integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sdt_transports.link_arret_cadre_horaire_objectid_link_arret_cadre_horaire_seq'::regclass),
    objectid_arret integer,
    objectid_cadre_horaire integer,
    user_mise_a_jour character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    date_mise_a_jour timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT link_arret_cadre_horaire_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid_link_arret_cadre_horaire)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);
```

## #Create relation trought Foreigns Keys

```sql
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS sdt_transports.link_arret_cadre_horaire
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (objectid_arret)
    REFERENCES sdt_transports.arret (objectid_arret) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS sdt_transports.link_arret_cadre_horaire
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (objectid_cadre_horaire)
    REFERENCES sdt_transports.cadre_horaire (objectid_cadre_horaire) MATCH SIMPLE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    NOT VALID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [doc](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#defining-1-n-relations) says:

> Relationship strength sets the strength of the relation between the
> parent and the child layer. The ***default* Association** type means that
> the parent layer is simply linked to the child one while the
> **Composition** type allows you to duplicate also the child features when
> duplicating the parent ones and on deleting a feature the children are
> deleted as well, resulting in cascade over all levels (means children
> of children of… are deleted as well).

There is no such settings to propagate duplication on the DB side, so it can't be retrieved and only the default "association" can be inferred.

We can confirm it in the [code](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/f4f9432232a60b2e303a523e1918ede2c571082d/src/providers/postgres/qgspostgresprovider.cpp#L5128): the relation strength is not read in Postgres (nor in Spatialite), so the default "Association" is used.